# How to transliterate 中文 in Mandarin pronunciation to Portuguese?

Tags: pronúncia

I am working on an art project that I would like to collect the hundreds of different transliterations of 「中文」 zhōng wén in Mandarin Chinese. (Pronunciation available here: [https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/中文](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87))

How can I transliterate zhōng wén in Portuguese? (For example, "zhong wen" would be the closest pronunciation in English.)

Comment: maybe "chong uene" or "xong uen"...

Comment: Hearing Google Translator pronunciation, it sounds like "xong uóóó".

Answer (score 3):

For European Portuguese, the best transliteration that I can find is:

> xhoun'uén

Explanation:

- We don't have the "xh" sound, but neither does English have "zh".
  I think it would be understood.
  We could also use "ch" instead of "x" here - it has this same sound.
  But with "ch" I can't find a way to mark the light separation between the consonants and the vowels - the h in "zhōng".
- The "ou" could mean a longer o sound ("[ch**ou**po](https://forvo.com/word/choupo/#pt)"), but also a sound like the name of the vowel "o" in English: /ou/ .
- The apostrophe is used in Portuguese to mark [elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) of letters, mostly in informal speech.
- The "é" is an /ɛ/, an open e. (see http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/ )

Comment: I am interested in seeing alternative answers, at least one with a Brasilian Portuguese transliteration. :) I expect it to be different.

Comment: OK, I provided one. :)

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but since a pt-BR is still missing, I can offer my opinion:

**tchôun'uén**

Where my changes with respect to ANeves' [answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4390/2764) (`xhoun'uén`) are only two: 1) `xh` to `tch`, like in the Portuguese "tchau" or English "[chore](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/chore)", and 2) `o` to `ô` in order to make both emphasis and closeness explicit. I'm not sure the `e` is really that open to warrant the acute accent, but it's probably good to have it there to counteract a bit the nasalization of the final `n`.

Comment: I like the extra circumflex accent on the o. It's not needed in pt-PT (with our accent we'd never open the "ou"), but I understand how it is necessary for pt-BR. :)

Comment: @ANeves It would unusual in pt-BR too, though more likely if someone is trying to fake a Chinese accent ;-) but it's mostly for stress.